# Mass rename objects on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Is it possible to mass rename objects on Google Cloud Storage using gsutil (or some other tool)? I am trying to figure out a way to rename a bunch of images from *.JPG to *.jpg.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a native way to do this in bash with an explanation below, line by line of the code:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket_name/*.JPG > src-rename-list.txt
sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/g' src-rename-list.txt > dest-rename-list.txt
paste -d ' ' src-rename-list.txt dest-rename-list.txt | sed -e 's/^/gsutil\ mv\ /' | while read line; do bash -c "$line"; done
rm src-rename-list.txt; rm dest-rename-list.txt
```

The solution pushes 2 lists, one for the source and one for the destination file (to be used in the "gsutil mv" command):

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket_name/*.JPG > src-rename-list.txt
sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/g' src-rename-list.txt > dest-rename-list.txt
```

The line "gsutil mv " and the two files are concatenated line by line using the below code:

```
paste -d ' ' src-rename-list.txt dest-rename-list.txt | sed -e 's/^/gsutil\ mv\ /'
```

This then runs each line in a while loop:
while read line; do bash -c "$line"; done

Lastly, clean up and delete the files created:

```
rm src-rename-list.txt; rm dest-rename-list.txt
```

The above has been tested against a working Google Storage bucket.

Comment: liked the solution, only small comment, instead of: 
gsutil ls gs://bucket_name/*.JPG | sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/g' > dest-rename-list.txt
simples to:
cat src-rename-list.txt | sed 's/\.JPG/\.jpg/g' > dest-rename-list.txt

Answer (score 4):

<strike>https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames</strike>

> gsutil supports URI wildcards

**EDIT**

[gsutil 3.0 release note](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/%23!topic/gs-discussion/5K9rReneQK8)

> As part of the bucket sub-directory support we changed the * wildcard to match only up to directory boundaries, and introduced the new ** wildcard...

Do you have directories under bucket? if so, maybe you need to go down to each directories or use **.

```
gsutil -m mv gs://my_bucket/**.JPG gs://my_bucket/**.jpg
```

or

```
gsutil -m mv gs://my_bucket/mydir/*.JPG gs://my_bucket/mydir/*.jpg
```

**EDIT**
gsutil doesn't support wildcard for destination so far (as of 4/12/'14)
nether [API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/).

so at this moment you need to retrieve list of all JPG files,
and rename each files.

python example:

```
import subprocess
files = subprocess.check_output("gsutil ls gs://my_bucket/*.JPG",shell=True)
files = files.split("\n")[:-1]
for f in files:
    subprocess.call("gsutil mv %s %s"%(f,f[:-3]+"jpg"),shell=True)
```

please note that this would take hours.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't seem to work, comes up with "CommandException: Destination (gs://my_bucket/*.jpg) must match exactly 1 URL"

Comment: I edited :) sorry I don't have environment to test now, if not work I would test some other ways

Comment: Nah the directories are right. I think the issue is that it doesn't do wildcard replacement?

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work. It seems you have to do rename one by one after retrieving file list, even inefficient.. And GCS API doesn't seem to have copy/rename function..

Answer (score 3):

gsutil does not support parallelized and mass-copy/rename.

You have two options:

- use a dataflow process to do the operation
  or
- use GNU parallel to launch it using several processes

If you use GNU Parallel, it is better to deploy a new instance to do the mass copy/rename operation:

- First: - Make a list of files you want to copy/rename (a file with source and destination separated by a space or tab), like this:

```sh
gs://origin_bucket/path/file gs://dest_bucket/new_path/new_filename
```

- Second: Launch a new compute instance
- Third: Login in that instance and install Gnu parallel

```sh
sudo apt install parallel
```

- Third: *authorize* yourself with google (gcloud auth login) because the service account for compute might not have permissions to move/rename the files.

```sh
gcloud auth login
```

- Make the copy (gsutil cp) or move (gsutil mv) operation with parallel:

```sh
   parallel -j 20 --colsep ' ' gsutil mv {1} {2} :::: file_with_source_destination_uris.txt
```

This will make 20 parallel runs of the gsutil cp operation.

Comment: Love `parallel` utility! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible:

[Move/rename objects and/or subdirectories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv)

Comment: Seen that but not quite sure how it helps me mass rename objects?

Comment: @Andrei but I can't use gsutil + subprocess on my gae project

Comment: You don't need gsutil in a GAE project. You can simply retrieve a list of objects in your code and rename them.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Currently I'm using [gcs client library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/tree/master/python) to copy,list,stat,delete files stored in gcs. I also need to implement renaming folders. That client lib don't have any methods for renaming.

Comment: So, what I'm going to do is, 1.create a new folder. 2. Copy all the contents of old folder into the newer one. 3. Delete the old folder . But it seems a long process..

Comment: Cloud storage objects are immutable, so renaming and replacing is the same.

Comment: Not sure if you can help. I tried this method and it didn't find the file with the prefix, it seems like it's looking to exactly match the path I put as opposed to a file with that prefix

Comment: Can you provide an example?