# Is it possible to rename all files/blobs in google storage that start with a given string?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I can see on the docs how to rename files (blobs) in a bucket.  However, I am looking for way to rename only those files/blobs that start with a specific prefix in a bucket (ie. renaming using wildcard like gs://my-bucket/loc/my-file*) 
I don't see a blob "name" property in the docs to try to match to after getting list of blobs in a bucket.
Is there a way to do that using Python language?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mass rename objects on Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166441/mass-rename-objects-on-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gsutil, it is possible to use wildcard naming and rename all files starting with a prefix to another name.

Comment: Can you give me an example? For example, what if i want to rename mulitple files gs://dir_1/abc_test_* to  gs://dir_2/test_*